# Unable to provision k8s from gcloud: "Account does not exist"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to provision a k8s cluster on Google Cloud Platform using `gcloud`

```
$ gcloud container clusters create my-cluster

ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=400,
message=service account "xxxxxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com" does not exist.
```

Any idea as to why this is error is occurring? I have been able to provision in the past w/o any issue until now.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the active account is your own account, and not a service account that lacks permission to create clusters.

Example command to check this and output:

```
$  gcloud auth list
Credentialed Accounts:
 - xxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com 
 - user@example.com ACTIVE
```

If you don't see `ACTIVE` next to the expected account, then set it to the right account with:

```
$ gcloud config set account <correctaccountname>
```

Maybe you switched to the service account a while back and forgot about it?

Comment: It seems that I do have an active account, will be following up with Google support. Will post any solutions I get back.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while creating a cluster using GKE. Earlier I was getting this error because I did not attach the service account (which needs to be created and assigned with a role having Kubernetes specific permissions).

Now, the further question you might have where to attach the service account, for this you need to go the Create Cluster --> Node Pool Section --> More Options --> (a new window will popup) --> security section --> In-Service account dropdown Choose the Service account.

Once you do it, then save and say create a cluster, hopefully you will not get the same error.