# Use Workload Identity to export GCP Cloud SQL databases to a bucket

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-sql, k8s-serviceaccount

I am working on a Kubernetes CronJob in GKE to [export SQL databases from GCP Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/exporting). I have a single GCP Cloud SQL instance whose Google service account is `p848827672298-eef1pd@gcp-sa-cloud-sql.iam.gserviceaccount.com`. If I add to this service account the permission to access and create bucket objects, running the `gcloud sql export sql ...` command *works*: the database is exported to my bucket.

However, what I want to do is use [Workload Identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity) to bind a Kubernetes service account to the `p848827...` Google service account so that the CronJob can export the Cloud SQL database to my bucket. I try to do this by running this command:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding \
  --role roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser \
  --member "serviceAccount:PROJECT_ID.svc.id.goog[K8_NAMESPACE/K8_SERVICE_ACCOUNT]" \
  p848827672298-eef1pd@gcp-sa-cloud-sql.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

(Of course, I replaced `PROJECT_ID`, `K8_NAMESPACE`, and `K8_SERVICE_ACCOUNT` with the appropriate values for my project.)

This results in

```
ERROR: (gcloud.iam.service-accounts.add-iam-policy-binding) NOT_FOUND: Service account projects/PROJECT_ID/serviceAccounts/p848827672298-eef1pd@gcp-sa-cloud-sql.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not exist.
```

How do I bind the Cloud SQL service account to my Kubernetes service account?

Answer (score 1):

Hope your API enabled, please trying disabling and enabling API once faced once similar issue and worked: `gcloud services  enable compute.googleapis.com`
https://dzone.com/articles/enabling-gke-workload-identity

If you have a serviceaccount JSON file you can directly inject it to POD also as volume mount secret also.

```
kubectl create secret generic echo --from-file service-account.json
```

Now suppose you are deploying the application with the secret injection

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: echo
  labels:
    app: echo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: echo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: echo
      name: echo
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: echo
          image: "gcr.io/hightowerlabs/echo"
          env:
            - name: "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"
              value: "/var/run/secret/cloud.google.com/service-account.json"
            - name: "PROJECT_ID"
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: echo
                  key: project-id
            - name: "TOPIC"
              value: "echo"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: "service-account"
              mountPath: "/var/run/secret/cloud.google.com"
            - name: "certs"
              mountPath: "/etc/ssl/certs"
      volumes:
        - name: "service-account"
          secret:
            secretName: "echo"
        - name: "certs"
          hostPath:
            path: "/etc/ssl/certs"
```

Example : https://github.com/kelseyhightower/gke-service-accounts-tutorial#google-cloud-service-accounts-with-google-container-engine-gke---tutorial

Comment: When I ran the command I _did_ replace the parameters in all-caps with the correct values for my project. When posting my question I used generic strings to more clearly indicate what is supposed to go there.

Comment: Also please check once : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44788915/unable-to-provision-k8s-from-gcloud-account-does-not-exist/60247423#60247423